# Android Icon Menu item don't see correct

Tags: android, icons

I am trying to make custom menu with my custom icons in Android 2.3.3 but its show dark.

In menu drawer.xml i have this code:

```
<item android:title="Configuración">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/configuracion"
            android:icon="@drawable/count_notification"
            android:title="Configuración" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/cerrar_sesion"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close"
            android:title="Cerrar Sesión" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

In Menu drawer in android device show this (icon shows dark):

[image]

But I have icon correct in drawable directory in hdpi, dpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi

And icon, if i open it, show correctly

Anybody knows how can I solve it?

Comment: This is a programming site, not a photography site. Please, post your code, not a picture of your code. We want to copy, paste, and debug your code, not critique its perspective and color.

Comment: Sorry, yet i change it

Comment: set mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); on your navigation view.

Comment: @sumitsingh its correct your solution! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sumitsingh!!

This is the solution:

In NavigationView setIconTintList to null.

```
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```